# Appium & Java : how to perform fast click actions?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I would like to perform 10 quick clicks action on a button in an Android app (prefer 0.5s), but following 10 clicks' gap is too long (approx 1.5 sec gap).
Wondering what is the proper way to shorten the gap between each click in Appium Java?
Thank you in advance :)

```
 for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
     driver.findElement(By.id("btnA")).click();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions but still it was not fast enough for my use case, So instead of using Appium I tried to click using adb command and it worked for me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input tap " + xOffSet + " " + yOffSet);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at TouchAction/MultiAction class, where you can define sequence of events and then execute it at once: 
https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

In your case it might look like this (example of 2 clicks)

`MobileElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("btnA"))`
`TouchAction action0 = new TouchAction(driver).tap(el)`
`TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).tap(el)`
`MultiAction(driver).add(action0).add(action1).perform()`

Hope you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are finding the element each time in your for loop which takes the extra time you noticed. In order to shorten your time, it would be better if you find the element once and click on it as many times as you want.

E.g.

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("btnA"));
for(int i=1; i<11; i++) {
  element.click();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Wasiq Bhamla thanks for your reply, and i've tried your method but the gap time between each click still too long, which i need really fast 10 clicks to launch a hidden menu...i've tried findElement by xpath, but still no luck, wondering if there's any other way? or it's just simply the limitation of Appium for now? (btw i'm using  io.appium 6.0.0-BETA4) THANK YOU!

Comment: There must be some internal Appium processing which is taking up that extra time you noticed. You can raise an issue with Appium Java client repo on GitHub and they should be able to identify where it's taking time.

Comment: Thanks @Wasiq Bhamla, i've posted my question in Appium's forum now: https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-java-how-to-perform-fast-click-actions/21567

Answer (score 0):

- Your method took me **5882ms**.
- Wasiq Bhamla method took me **3622ms**.
- dmle does not work, because thats simultaneous taps, so even with 10 TouchAction, it will tap once. Also its MultiTouchAction and tap(el) is deprecated.

  Using dmle idea of 10 independent taps:

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      new TouchAction(driver).tap(element).perform();
  }
  ```

  it took me **6915ms**
- Using .press(el).release().press(el)... with the code (also deprecated):

  ```
  TouchAction action =new TouchAction(driver);
  for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      action.press(element).release();
  }
  action.perform();
  ```

  it took me **25285ms** WOW

So Wasiq Bhamla method won... I'm using appium 1.8.0 beta 3 with java client 6.0.0 beta 4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi @tcardoso, thanks for your analysis, and i've tried Wasiq Bhamla's method but the gap time between each click still too long, which i need really fast 10 clicks to launch a hidden menu...i've tried findElement by xpath, but still no luck, wondering if there's any other way? or it's just simply the limitation of Appium for now? (btw i'm using  io.appium 6.0.0-BETA4) THANK YOU!